# Program stops running while accessing MongoDB in python program triggered using udev rules

Tags: pi-3, python-3, mongodb

I have `udev` rules file to run a program on usb mount. I am running a bash script `automount.sh` when USB is connected to Pi.

```
#! /bin/sh

cd
cd /root
chmod 777 /media/USB
chmod 777 create_report.py
python3 create_report.py
umount
```

Bash script is running fine and executing the python program, but the program stops running when it executes MongoDB query instruction and no exception is raised. Attached basic version of python script below.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
current_col = client.current_db.current_c
data  = current_col.fins_one()  #Program stops here
```

Program is executing completely when executed this program manually.

Comment: As soon as Udev processing is complete it will kill (without prejudice) any program or script that has been spawned by any Udev rule.

Comment: How to make the Udev process wait till program execution completes?

Comment: You can't. You'll need to find a better way to get the process running and triggered from a udev event.

Comment: I removed the MongoDB part from program, now the program completes execution even after adding delay in the program